# URP transparent game object causing weird clipping effect

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a game object in unity fade out using URP lit shaders and when I changed their material to Transparent instead of Opaque they look weird. How can I fix this?

[image]

This is my first time using URP so I've never had an issue like this.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a two sided transparent shader. It's a bit more complicated, but generally you shouldn't do that. The reason why it looks so weird has to do with how rendering works. Transparent materials don't overdraw themselves and instead just replace the pixel value. Depending on how the rounding goes you get either patches of the mesh from the outside or the inside.

[image]

Depending on what you want to achieve the solution can be as simple as unchecking two sided and as complicated as writing a volumetric shader.

On a standard lit shader you need to make sure that `Render Face` is **not** set to `Both`. Either set to `Front` (recomended) or `Back`.

[image]

Comment: Im just using the standard UniversalRenderPipelin/lit shader, how would I do that?

Comment: I tried rewriting the lit shader in shader graph from scratch (I am very new to shader graph) and now they are even worse and still has the same issue even with "two sided" checked off.

Comment: @TheDemonDonut I have updated my answer. Dunno about the problems you had with the "reconstruction", but it's not necessary. It is possible that you are encountering another common issue, so please get back to me if the problem persists.